# XSLT how to use a wildcard in template match

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to implement a sort of wildcard mechanism in match to be used in XSLT template.

My original problem is that I am looking for java code lines in a set of files. The lines I am looking for could be of this kind:

```
a.setValue(2);
System.out.println(a.toString());
a.getValue();
```

In this lines, `a` is not the exact variable name, but is a sort of placeholder. I am looking for three java code lines where the same variable is used in that way.

In order to achieve my goal, I thought about using XSLT, because with it I suppose to explain this kind of concepts.

With [srcml](http://www.srcml.org/#home) I translated java code in xml and this is the xml sheet where I have to look for java code lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit filename="Users/bibi/Documents/UniMi/CloudStation/TesiM/DSL/DSL/resources/src/src_beautified/strategy/StrategyExample.java" language="Java" revision="0.9.5" xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
<package>package 
    <name>strategy</name>
    ;</package>
<import>import 
    <name>
        <name>strategy</name>
        <operator>.</operator>
        <name>strategy</name>
        <operator>.</operator>
        <name>HelloWorld</name></name>;</import>
<import>import 
    <name>
        <name>strategy</name>
        <operator>.</operator>
        <name>strategy</name>
        <operator>.</operator>
        <name>SubArray</name></name>;</import>
<class>
    <specifier>public</specifier>class 
    <name>StrategyExample</name>
    <block>
        {

        <function>
            <specifier>public</specifier>
            <specifier>static</specifier>
            <type>
                <name>void</name></type>
            <name>main</name>
            <parameter_list>(
                <parameter>
                    <decl>
                        <type>
                            <name>
                                <name>String</name>
                                <index>[]</index></name>
                        </type>
                        <name>args</name>
                    </decl>
                </parameter>)</parameter_list>
            <block>{

                <decl_stmt>
                    <decl>
                        <type>
                            <name>MyArray</name></type>
                        <name>m</name>
                        <init>= 
                            <expr>
                                <operator>new</operator>
                                <call>
                                    <name>MyArray</name>
                                    <argument_list>
                                        (
                                        <argument>
                                            <expr>
                                                <literal type="number">10</literal></expr>
                                        </argument>)</argument_list>
                                </call>
                            </expr>
                        </init>
                    </decl>;</decl_stmt>
                <decl_stmt>
                    <decl>
                        <type>
                            <name>HelloWorld</name>
                        </type>
                        <name>hw</name>
                        <init>= 
                            <expr>
                                <operator>new</operator>
                                <call>
                                    <name>HelloWorld</name>
                                    <argument_list>()</argument_list></call>
                            </expr>
                        </init>
                    </decl>;</decl_stmt>
                <expr_stmt>
                    <expr>
                        <call>
                            <name>
                                <name>System</name>
                                <operator>.</operator>
                                <name>out</name>
                                <operator>.</operator>
                                <name>println</name>
                            </name>
                            <argument_list>(
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <call>
                                            <name>
                                                <name>hw</name>
                                                <operator>.</operator>
                                                <name>getString</name></name>
                                            <argument_list>(
                                                <argument>
                                                    <expr>
                                                        <literal type="string">&quot;prova&quot;</literal></expr>
                                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                                        </call>
                                        <operator>.</operator>
                                        <call>
                                            <name>substring</name>
                                            <argument_list>(
                                                <argument>
                                                    <expr>
                                                        <literal type="number">0</literal></expr>
                                                </argument>, 
                                                <argument>
                                                    <expr>
                                                        <literal type="number">3</literal></expr>
                                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                                        </call>
                                    </expr>
                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                        </call>
                    </expr>;</expr_stmt>
                <expr_stmt>
                    <expr>
                        <call>
                            <name>
                                <name>m</name>
                                <operator>.</operator>
                                <name>setValue</name>
                            </name>
                            <argument_list>(
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <literal type="number">1</literal></expr>
                                </argument>, 
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <literal type="number">6</literal></expr>
                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                        </call>
                    </expr>;</expr_stmt>
                <expr_stmt>
                    <expr>
                        <call>
                            <name>
                                <name>m</name>
                                <operator>.</operator>
                                <name>setValue</name>
                            </name>
                            <argument_list>(
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <literal type="number">0</literal></expr>
                                </argument>, 
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <literal type="number">8</literal></expr>
                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                        </call>
                    </expr>;</expr_stmt>
                <expr_stmt>
                    <expr>
                        <call>
                            <name>
                                <name>hw</name>
                                <operator>.</operator>
                                <name>getString</name>
                            </name>
                            <argument_list>(
                                <argument>
                                    <expr>
                                        <operator>new</operator>
                                        <call>
                                            <name>String</name>
                                            <argument_list>
                                                (
                                                <argument>
                                                    <expr>
                                                        <literal type="string">&quot;ciao&quot;</literal></expr>
                                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                                        </call>
                                    </expr>
                                </argument>)</argument_list>
                        </call>
                    </expr>;</expr_stmt>
                }</block>
        </function>}</block>
</class>
```

In this example, I would like to look for this two lines:

```
m.setValue( 1 , 6 );
m.setValue( 0 , 8 );
```

The xpath match to be used in xslt template that I have produced in order to catch this line, is this one:

```
src:expr_stmt
[src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:operator='.'][src:name='setValue']]
[src:argument_list
[src:argument[src:expr[src:literal='1'][src:literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]
[src:argument[src:expr[src:literal='6'][src:literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]]]]
[following-sibling::*[2][self::src:expr_stmt
[src:expr[src:call[src:name[src:name[matches(@name, preceding-sibling::*[2]/@src_expr/src_call/src_name/src:name)]
[src:operator='.'][src:name='setValue']]
[src:argument_list[src:argument[src:expr[src:literal='0'][src:literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]
[src:argument[src:expr[src:literal='8'][src:literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]]]]]]]
```

But it is not working because it selects all the `src:expr_stmt` node.

 Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please state your input xml as well. [mcve] is appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here? Surely there must be a simpler method?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I need something like a placeholder. I would like to build a sort of wildcard mechanism. And in order to do this I need a way to express the attribute value of the preceding sibling.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't mean anything to me. I suspect this is an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/). I asked what is the **real** problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: The real problem is that I need a way to select, in Java code, a set of code lines where there is the same variable (but I do not know the variable name) used in different situations. In order to do this, I use srcml and I convert Java to xml and then I need a way to select the lines I am interested in and I would like to use xslt to do this .

Comment: To me " I need a way to select [...] a set of code lines where there is the same variable" sounds like with XSLT you want to group or key on the type element representing a variable name.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The issue with xsl key, is that I don't know how to match variable name involved in specific java code lines.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time trying to understand what this means: _"
In this lines, a is not the exact variable name, but is a sort of placeholder. I am looking for three java code lines where the same variable is used in that way."_ What is "sort of a placeholder", and what "in that way" are you referring to? It's also not clear at all what you mean by "wildcard" throughout this question.

Comment: @JLRishe _a sort of place holder_  would like to tell that I am looking for three line of codes like the one I wrote, but it is not mandatory that the variable name is a. I want to match three lines where the methods invocated are the ones I wrote with those arguments and the variable that invokes them is always the same but with any name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly now, I think that keys would help in solving this. Here is an XSLT for the latter example you provided (with the two `.setValue`s):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:src="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- key for first statement pattern -->    
  <xsl:key name="expr1"
           match="src:expr_stmt[src:expr/src:call[
                      src:name[src:operator = '.' and src:name[2] = 'setValue']
                      and
                      src:argument_list[
                          src:argument[1]/src:expr/src:literal = 1 and
                          src:argument[2]/src:expr/src:literal = 6
                      ]
                  ]]"
           use="src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]"
   />
  <!-- key for second statement pattern -->
  <xsl:key name="expr2"
           match="src:expr_stmt[src:expr/src:call[
                      src:name[src:operator = '.' and src:name[2] = 'setValue']
                      and
                      src:argument_list[
                          src:argument[1]/src:expr/src:literal = 0 and
                          src:argument[2]/src:expr/src:literal = 8
                      ]
                  ]]"
           use="src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]"
   />



  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <n>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </n>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- breakdown of this expression:
       count(key('N', path)) = count(. | key('N', path)) -> the current node is in key N

       (the current node is in key expr1 OR
        the current node is in key expr2) 
       AND
       there is a node in key expr1 for the current node's first src:name 
       AND
       there is a node in key expr2 for the current node's first src:name
  -->
  <xsl:template match="src:expr_stmt[(count(key('expr1', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1])) = 
                                      count(. | key('expr1', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1])) or
                                      count(key('expr2', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1])) = 
                                      count(. | key('expr2', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]))) 
                                     and
                                     key('expr1', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]) 
                                     and 
                                     key('expr2', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1])]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your example XML, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<n xmlns:src="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
  <expr_stmt xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
    <expr>
      <call>
        <name>
          <name>m</name>
          <operator>.</operator>
          <name>setValue</name>
        </name>
        <argument_list>
          (
          <argument>
            <expr>
              <literal type="number">1</literal>
            </expr>
          </argument>,
          <argument>
            <expr>
              <literal type="number">6</literal>
            </expr>
          </argument>)
        </argument_list>
      </call>
    </expr>;
  </expr_stmt>
  <expr_stmt xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
    <expr>
      <call>
        <name>
          <name>m</name>
          <operator>.</operator>
          <name>setValue</name>
        </name>
        <argument_list>
          (
          <argument>
            <expr>
              <literal type="number">0</literal>
            </expr>
          </argument>,
          <argument>
            <expr>
              <literal type="number">8</literal>
            </expr>
          </argument>)
        </argument_list>
      </call>
    </expr>;
  </expr_stmt>
</n>
```

Comment: I am sorry that I am not able to be more clear. I have edited my answer trying to explain my issue again.
What I am looking for is two lines where the same variable is used to invoke the method `setValue`, the first time with argument `(1, 6)` and the second with args `(0, 8)`.
I really appreciate your answer, but with your xpath I would match every two lines with `setValue(1, 6)` and `setValue(0, 8)` invocation, even if two different variables invoke that method.

Comment: you are totally helping me. I am trying to completely understand your answer. I am not able to understand in which part you are asking that key `expr1`is equal to key `expr2`. I obviously know this is my fault but I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @delca85 This part of the match expression will only be true if the `src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]` value for the current node is in both `expr1` and `expr2`: `key('expr1', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1]) 
                                     and 
                                     key('expr2', src:expr/src:call/src:name/src:name[1])`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I have understood the problem and I think it would be better if you posted a simplified input sample but as I can't really put attempts to discuss the problem into a comment I post this grouping suggestion as a discussion contribution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//expr_stmt[expr/call/name[name]]" group-by="expr/call/name/name">
            <variable name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <statement>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
                    </statement>                    
                </xsl:for-each>
            </variable>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this against the posted input sample with some closing tags added I get

```
<variable name="m">
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "mf-getFormatType-0" , behavior = "MathFormat.getFormatType.String[]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-mf.getFormatType-callActionExpr0" ) { mf . getFormatType () }}) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "m-printString-2" , behavior = "MyArray.printString.String[String-]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-m.printString-callActionExpr1" ) { m . printString ( "ciao" ) }}) . length () ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 1 , 6 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 0 , 8 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 4 , 1 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 9 , 7 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . getValue ( j ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( j , j + 1 ) ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="printString">
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "mf-getFormatType-0" , behavior = "MathFormat.getFormatType.String[]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-mf.getFormatType-callActionExpr0" ) { mf . getFormatType () }}) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "m-printString-2" , behavior = "MyArray.printString.String[String-]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-m.printString-callActionExpr1" ) { m . printString ( "ciao" ) }}) . length () ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="MyArray">
   <statement>MyArray . printValue () ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="printValue">
   <statement>MyArray . printValue () ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="setValue">
   <statement>m . setValue ( 1 , 6 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 0 , 8 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 4 , 1 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 9 , 7 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( j , j + 1 ) ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="getValue">
   <statement>m . getValue ( j ) ;</statement>
</variable>
```

Does that at least appear to be a step into solving your problem? It might be that the XPath or grouping can be tuned further by someone that understands the complex input format but perhaps the suggestion shows how to extract and group some elements in the format.

For instance with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//expr_stmt[expr/call/name[name]]" group-by="expr/call/name/name[1]">
        <variable name="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <statement>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
                </statement>                    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </variable>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

we only get

```
<variable name="m">
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "mf-getFormatType-0" , behavior = "MathFormat.getFormatType.String[]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-mf.getFormatType-callActionExpr0" ) { mf . getFormatType () }}) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . printString ( @ CallBehavior ( id = "m-printString-2" , behavior = "MyArray.printString.String[String-]" ) { @ CallAction ( id = "main-m.printString-callActionExpr1" ) { m . printString ( "ciao" ) }}) . length () ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 1 , 6 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 0 , 8 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 4 , 1 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 9 , 7 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . getValue ( j ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( j , j + 1 ) ;</statement>
</variable>
<variable name="MyArray">
   <statement>MyArray . printValue () ;</statement>
</variable>
```

Or

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//expr_stmt
        [expr[call[name[operator='.'][name='setValue']]
        [argument_list
        [argument[expr[literal= (1, 0)][literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]
        [argument[expr[literal= (6, 8)][literal[contains(@type, 'number')]]]]]]]" group-by="expr/call/name/name[1]">
        <variable name="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <statement>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
                </statement>                    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </variable>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

would give

```
<variable name="m">
   <statement>m . setValue ( 1 , 6 ) ;</statement>
   <statement>m . setValue ( 0 , 8 ) ;</statement>
</variable>
```